# Adding a banner to homepage on Shopify

Tags: css, content-management-system, shopify, liquid

I was trying to add a banner to Homepage in a website I am building in Shopify, but
my index.liquid file only includes this:

{{ content_for_index }}

Could anyone help with pointing where does content_for_index links to? (I am using Canopy theme if this helps) There is no file with this extension and I am not sure where does it link to...

Any tips would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To add content to the home page of a Shopify theme, you need to create a `section`. The details are here:

https://www.shopify.com.au/partners/blog/how-to-create-your-first-shopify-theme-section

Essentially, you will need to create a new file within the `sections` folder of your theme, named something like `banner.liquid`. This will contain HTML, and optionally Liquid and a schema.

The schema can define presets and content defined by the theme content manager, which means the content within the section can be dynamic.

For a section to work on the home page, `presets` must be defined in the schema:
https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/sections#static-and-dynamic-sections

Sections can be used throughout a Shopify theme to allow content managers to update a theme easily.

Once your section is created, you add it to the home page by navigating in the Shopify admin to:

`Online Store > Customize`

Then you will be able to add a section using the theme management interface.